# change date format in vaadin-grid

Tags: angular, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm pulling a Date from a database into the vaadin-grid(vaadin-table) with angular2. All I need is MM/DD/YYYY format. The date filters is not working in the vaadin-grid like {{dateOfBirth | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}.

Thank you! Examples make the most sense to me as I'm very new to vaadin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Vaadin polymer & angular2 because I mostly worked with *classic* Vaadin but looking at [their samples (currently line 182)](https://github.com/vaadin/expense-manager-demo/blob/master/src/expenses-list.html#L182), it looks like you can provide a renderer. The [expanse manager demo](https://wc.demo.vaadin.com/expense-manager/#/5a56905bc0) has a `Date` as its first column, and in the sources you can see the renderer as well, using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library:

```
grid.columns[0].renderer = function(cell) {
  cell.element.innerHTML = moment(cell.data).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
};
```

which generates:

[image]

If you take a look at [`moment.js`'s formatting options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you can change it to whatever you like, for example `DD/MM/YYYY`. Here's a basic [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x50q44rs/5/) doing just that (sorry, SO code snippet gave an error I could not figure out...).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting to DD/MM/YYYY of vaadin-date input when selecting a date(vaadin-date-picker).

```
toDDMMYYYY = function(dateFromInput){ //DD/MM/YYYY
           dateFromInput.set('i18n.formatDate', function(d) {
             var yearStr = d.getFullYear().toString();
             var dateFormatted =  d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + yearStr;
             return dateFormatted
           });
           dateFromInput.set('i18n.parseDate', function(t) {
             var parts = t.split('/');
             var today = new Date();
             var date, month = today.getMonth(), year = today.getFullYear();

             if (parts.length === 3) {
               year = parseInt(parts[2]);
               if (parts[2].length < 3 && year >= 0) {
                 year += year < 50 ? 2000 : 1900;
               }
               month = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
               date = parseInt(parts[0]);
             } else if (parts.length === 2) {
               month = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
               date = parseInt(parts[0]);
             } else if (parts.length === 1) {
               date = parseInt(parts[1]);
             }
             if (date !== undefined) {
               var result = new Date(0, 0); // Wrong date (1900-01-01), but with midnight in local time
               result.setFullYear(year);
               result.setMonth(month);
               result.setDate(date);
               return result;
             }
           });
         };
```